# Screen blackout when performing Pinch Gesture on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have this strange issue in iOS4 where in the Video which is playing in  `MPMoviePlayerController` blacks out when the user performs certain kind of gestures over the screen. I'm simply creating a `UIViewController` and object for `MPMoviePlayerController` and then setting the View onto the `UIViewController`.

I want to ask if this issue is solvable or not, and whats the correct way of playing a streaming video on iPhone.

And if there is way that I can use a overlay view over `MPMoviePlayerController` and capture all gestures and pass on single taps or touches to `MPMoviePlayerController` for general functionality of `MPMoviePlayerController` and avoiding Gestures that is causing the issue.

Please help me solving the problem with the Best possible solution and please help me in elaborating the solution.

Comment: I've seen this too. I've noticed that it is related to the events sent.. the pinch gesture is, like the toggle from embedded to fullscreen mode, probably sending the did finish playing event. I haven't been able to figure out why.

Answer (score 9):

Apple embedded `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` in `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, but it can't be found in `UIResponder.gestures` property.
You can disable `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` embedded in `touchesBegan` method of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        NSArray *array = touch.gestureRecognizers;
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in array) {
            if (gesture.enabled && [gesture isMemberOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
                gesture.enabled = NO;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I just found the reason of my problem from the Apple's doc:

> When you add a movie player’s view to your app’s view hierarchy, be sure to size the frame correctly, as shown here:
>
> ...
>
> [player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  **// player's frame must match parent's**
>
> ...

Now my pinches are not crashing my app.

Answer (score 0):

I hate this issue. What I have been able to find is that having full screen mode needs to have embedded control in order for the `NSNotificationCenter` to respond with the correct `Notification`. Sounds stupid and ridiculous, but this is what i've found in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue and found a simple workaround.

The above gesture-nuking trick could not be used as we do not want to use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` (we have some custom controls when the video is not in fullscreen and would like to keep the smooth transition).

**Symptoms (iOS 5.1):**

- When the user repeatedly opened a video in fullscreen, pinched it back out of fullscreen and then did the same with a new video the screen would go black the 5th time a video was started and entered fullscreen.
- While the screen is blacked out it is possible to hide and show the status bar by single tapping, but no video or navigation bar appears.
- Using the "Done" button in fullscreen instead of pinch it was possible to close fullscreen without any problems ever.
- We allocate a fresh `MPMoviePlayerController` for each video and don't leak anything. This did not help.

**Workaround:**

When dismissing the view which had the `MPMoviePlayerController` view in it we set `contentURL = nil` on the player.

After that we have no problems with black screen on subsequent `MPMoviePlayerController` instances.

It seems there is some internal cleanup which is performed when using the "Done" button, but not when pinching to close fullscreen.